# How to get value from a variable and multiple with other variable

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

//create contract

contract MyToken{
    uint price;
    address public minter;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;
    event Sent (address from, address to, uint amount);
    
    constructor() {
        minter= msg.sender;
        
    }

    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        require(msg.sender==minter);
        balances[receiver]+=amount;
    }

    function send(address receiver, uint amount) public {
        require(amount<=balances[msg.sender],"insufficent amount");
        balances[msg.sender]-=amount;
        balances[receiver]+=amount;
       emit Sent(msg.sender,receiver,amount);
    }

    function setprice(uint x)public{
        price=x;
    }

    function bill() public returns (uint) {
        uint bill=price*balances[receiver];
        return bill;
    }
    
}
```

I am getting an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same name `bill` for a function and a variable

```
function bill() public returns (uint) {
    uint bill=price*balances[receiver];
    return bill;
}
```